# How to get inner join query with filtered data in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need the data on OP10 Start time of first entry and End time of last entry.i.e(OP10 Start Time : 10 am and End Time : 11.10am).Like wise OP20 and OP30.To avoid the multiple reports on same data(OP10),Give me ITS start & Ending Time is enough.

**SQL Table Result:**

```
+---------+------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|   Line     Operation |     StartDate               |   EndDate                   |
+---------+------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|   ACOE  | OP10       | 2017-01-27 10:00:00.000     |  2017-01-27  10:10:00.000   |
|   ACOE  | OP10       | 2017-01-27 11:00:00.000     |  2017-01-27  11:10:00.000   |
|   ACOE  | OP20       | 2017-01-27 11:10:00.000     |  2017-01-27  11:15:00.000   |
|   ACOE  | OP20       | 2017-01-27 11:20:00.000     |  2017-01-27  11:25:00.000   |
|   ACOE  | OP30       | 2017-01-27 12:10:00.000     |  2017-01-27  12:15:00.000   |
|   ACOE  | OP30       | 2017-01-27 12:20:00.000     |  2017-01-27  12:25:00.000   |
+---------+------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

**Need Output like as below format:**

```
+---------+------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|   Line     Operation |     StartDate               |   EndDate                   |
+---------+------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|   ACOE  | OP10       | 2017-01-27 10:00:00.000     |  2017-01-27  11:10:00.000   |
|   ACOE  | OP20       | 2017-01-27 11:10:00.000     |  2017-01-27  11:25:00.000   |
|   ACOE  | OP30       | 2017-01-27 12:10:00.000     |  2017-01-27  12:25:00.000   |
+---------+------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT Line, Operation, StartDate = MIN(StartDate), EndDate=MAX(EndDate)
GROUP BY Line, Operation
ORDER BY Line, Operation
```

Let me know
Ciao

Comment: But using inner join query this syntax StartDate = MIN(StartDate), EndDate=MAX(EndDate) thrown error.

Comment: the sintax I write to you its ok... can u post your complete query?